# Outlook API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, api, outlook

I'm trying to access the Office 365 API to read the users calendar events. This happens inside a Chat Bot (MS Bot Framework) with the library [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/).
After the login process the access token can be returned with `context.GetAccessToken("https://graph.windows.net")`.
This seems to work as a valid token is returned.

Next I tried to request some resources from `Office365` and almost all attempts have resulted in a `401`. In Azure AD the app has access to all permissions in the `Office 365` Exchange Group.

When I try to access the discovery `API` at `api.office.com/discovery/v1.0` it is the only time the request doesn't result in 401:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync("me"))
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

What gets returned is this

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<service xml:base=\"https://api.office.com/discovery/me/\" 
    xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/app\" 
    xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">
<workspace>
    <atom:title type=\"text\">Default</atom:title>
    <collection href=\"allservices\">
        <atom:title type=\"text\">allservices</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href=\"services\">
        <atom:title type=\"text\">services</atom:title>
    </collection>
</workspace>
</service>
```

After that I tried accessing some information in two ways. The `OutlookServicesClient`:

```
OutlookServicesClient wat = new OutlookServicesClient(baseUrl, async () => token);
var messages = await wat.Me.Messages.ExecuteAsync();
```

And a manual way using `HttpClient`:

```
AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/"+ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AAD.Tenant"]);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await auth.AcquireTokenAsync(
            "https://outlook.office365.com/", 
            new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AAD.ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AAD.ClientSecret"])
            );
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events");
```

Both return `401`. I tried two different resources: `https://graph.windows.net/` for the authentication bot which returned a shorter token that didn't include roles; and `https://outlook.office365.com/` for the manual method which returned a longer token with roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out:

`https://graph.windows.net` seems to be a newer version which is not yet supported by my `Outlook365` tenant. Hence the `401`. When i switched to `https://outlook.office365.com` for the authbot it returned the correct results (calendars and events).

For the manual mode I assume `https://login.windows.net` is yet another domain apart from graph that is not compatible.

Side note: Using `outlook.office365.com` I got a `404` at first. This was a result of the user being used for testing not having an inbox.